# Android : ListView not appearing or not showing in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I'm trying to implement populate `listview` from `SQLite` , but the android suddenly `listview` is not appearing on screen.What is the wrong in my code.

here is my `ListView` Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_AllPost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:longClickable="true"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Activity code

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_AllPost);
        populateList();
 private void populateList() {

        descArray.clear();
        List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions();
        for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc)
        {
            String strInspectorname = all_Post.getStringInspectorname();
            Log.e("strInspectorname "," = " + strInspectorname);
            descArray.add(all_Post);
        }

        if (adapter == null)
        {
            adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else if (adapter != null) {

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show `AllPostAdapter ` class code

Comment: Sorry i can't because of huge code in AllPostAdapter  class

Comment: Please recheck if you have do right query on dbhelper.getAllDescriptions()

Comment: put debug point on `List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions();` line and make sure you are getting data from database

Comment: Yeh sure getting all data from database in List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions();

Comment: instead of `"huge code in AllPostAdapter class"` why dont you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: Uploading , Downloading , camera , popup window this all are Can it possible in SimpleCursorAdapter class

Comment: Everything looks fine, so the problem has to be in your adapter.
Maybe you dont do the right things in the getView()?
Or u have override the getCount()-method and return 0?

There can be a lot reasons for this behavior. Give us a part of your adapter-logic.

Comment: Can i post only getView() method please.

Comment: In adapter class the char is above 30000, so i cant post the getView() method

Comment: `"Uploading , Downloading , camera , popup window"` are you doing all this stuff in your adapter class??

Comment: doing upload , camera and two popup view in Adapter class.